# Flowchart where the nodes are pspictures

Tags: pstricks, psmatrix

I want to create a flowchart, in which every node is itself a pspicture (with nodes and arrows), and there are arrows between the pspictures themselves. Here is an example (which looks bad because I had to manually place the text and the arrows):

[image]

Currently, I am creating the arrows manually, but I am sure this is not the right way to do it. Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,,section]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}

\usepackage[crop=on]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}

% 

\newcommand{\action}[1] {
  \rput(-1.5,-.5){#1}
}

\newcommand{\goleft}[1] {
  \pcline[linecolor=black]{->}(-4,-0.5)(-5,-1.5)\bput(.5){\emph{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\godown}[1] {
  \pcline[linecolor=black]{->}(-1.5,-0.5)(-1.5,-1.5)\aput(.5){\emph{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\goright}[1] {
  \pcline[linecolor=black]{->}(1.5,-0.5)(2.5,-1.5)\aput(.5){\emph{#1}}
}

%

\newcommand{\agent}[1]{\circlenode[linecolor=white]{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}} 
\newcommand{\piece}[1]{\dianode[linecolor=white]{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}} 
\newcommand{\like}[2]{\ncline[linecolor=green]{->}{#1}{#2}} 
\newcommand{\likenext}[2]{\ncline[linecolor=gray,linestyle=dashed]{->}{#1}{#2}} 
\newcommand{\likemaybe}[2]{\ncline[linecolor=gray,linestyle=dashed]{->}{#1}{#2}} 
\newcommand{\threeagents}{
\agent{A}  \agent{B}  \agent{C}  

\vspace{7mm}

\piece{1}  \piece{2}  \piece{3}
}
\newcommand{\fouragents}{
\agent{A} & \agent{B} & \agent{C} & \agent{D}  \\
\piece{1} & \piece{2} & \piece{3} & \piece{4}
}
\psset{colsep=0.5cm,rowsep=1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0,rowsep=1.7]
    \makebox[5cm] {
    }
&
    \makebox[5cm] {
        Start
        \goleft{B,C,D have 3 neighbors}
        \godown{2 neighbors}
        \goright{1 neighbor}
    }
&
    \makebox[5cm] {
    }

\\

    \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0cm]
    \fouragents

    \like{A}{1}\like{A}{2}\like{A}{3}\like{A}{4}
    \like{B}{2}
    \like{C}{3}
    \like{D}{4}

    \end{psmatrix}
    \action{Done}
&
    \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0cm]
    \fouragents

    \like{A}{1}\like{A}{2}\like{A}{3}\like{A}{4}
    \like{B}{1}
    \like{C}{4}
    \like{D}{4}
    \end{psmatrix}

    \goleft{}
    \godown{}
&
    \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0cm]
    \fouragents

    \like{A}{1}\like{A}{2}\like{A}{3}\like{A}{4}
    \like{B}{4}
    \like{C}{4}
    \like{D}{4}
    \end{psmatrix}
\\

    \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0cm]
    \fouragents

    \like{A}{2}\like{A}{3}\like{A}{4}
    \like{B}{1}\like{B}{2}
    \like{C}{4}
    \like{D}{4}
    \end{psmatrix}
&

    \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0cm]
    \fouragents

    \like{A}{2}\like{A}{3}
    \like{B}{1}\like{B}{2}
    \like{C}{4}\like{C}{2}
    \like{D}{4}
    \end{psmatrix}
&
%%%

\end{psmatrix}
\\
\\


\end{document}
```

I am trying to create arrows from the "start" psmatrix to each of the psmatrix-es in the next row. But this doesn't look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example which shows that you can work with symbolic names for the cells:

```
\documentclass[11pt,,section]{article}

\usepackage[crop=on]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\def\Line{\ncline[arrows=->,linecolor=green]}

\begin{document}

\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=3cm,rowsep=1.7]
  & [name=start] Start & \\[1cm]
[name=Aleft]  
 \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0.5cm,rowsep=0mm]
     A & B & C & D \\[12mm]
     1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
     \psspan{3}Done
    \Line{1,1}{2,1}\Line{1,2}{2,2}\Line{1,3}{2,3}\Line{1,4}{2,4}
    \Line{1,1}{2,2}\Line{1,1}{2,3}\Line{1,1}{2,4}
 \end{psmatrix}
& [name=Acenter]
 \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0.5cm,rowsep=0mm]
     A & B & C & D \\[12mm]
     1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    \Line{1,1}{2,1}\Line{1,2}{2,1}\Line{1,3}{2,4}\Line{1,4}{2,4}
    \Line{1,1}{2,2}\Line{1,1}{2,3}\Line{1,1}{2,4}
 \end{psmatrix}
& [name=Aright]
 \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0.5cm,rowsep=0mm]
     A & B & C & D \\[12mm]
     1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    \Line{1,1}{2,1}\Line{1,2}{2,4}\Line{1,3}{2,4}\Line{1,4}{2,4}
    \Line{1,1}{2,2}\Line{1,1}{2,3}\Line{1,1}{2,4}
 \end{psmatrix}
\end{psmatrix}
\ncline[nodesepA=2mm,offsetB=-15mm]{start}{Aleft}\nbput{B,C,D have 3 neighbors}
\ncline[nodesep=2mm]{start}{Acenter}\ncput*{2 neighbors}
\ncline[nodesepA=2mm,offsetB=10mm]{start}{Aright}\naput{1 neighbor}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this and got two empty pages. But the problem was solved after I moved the last three "\ncline" statements above the last "\end{psmatrix}". Thanks!

Comment: ah yes, I didn't ude `auto-pst-pdf`. The reason why it works in both ways. I always use `xelatex`

Answer (score 2):

I simplified your code. One `psmatrix` environment is enough. Is that like you want?

```
\documentclass[11pt,,section]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-tree}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\agent}[1]{\circlenode[linecolor=white]{#1}{{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\like}[2]{\ncline[linecolor=green]{->}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}\color{blue}
\psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.25, colsep=0.75cm, nodesep=2pt}
\begin{psmatrix}
  & \agent{Start}\\
  \agent{A} & & \agent{E}\\
  \agent{B} & [mnode=oval, linecolor=white]\agent{C}\hspace{1.5cm}\agent{D} & \agent{F}
  \ncline{Start}{A}
  \ncline{Start}{3,2}
  \ncline{Start}{E}
  \psset{linecolor=green}
  \ncline{A}{B}
  \ncline{F}{E}
  \ncline{C}{D}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually my use-case is more complicated (I tried to simplify it but probably over-simplified), because in every frame there are the same letters: A,B,C,D and more.  So I cannot just send arrows from Start to different letters.

Comment: I guessed so, but I'm sure it can be simplified. Could you at least post the scan of a drawing of what you try to achieve?

Comment: Perfect. I'll look at it later today.